# I want to pass a value from search query to hidden field

Tags: php, jquery

I have a live search form on the site that does two things. If it gets any results it displays them, and if not, the visitor can send an email.

There are two input type fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="myField" id="myField" value="" />
Email: <input name="email-index" id="email-index" type="text" /></b>
```

In the email field, the visitor inputs the email. And in the value of the hidden field, i want the search query to be passed from the query.

The search query results are displayed one div before this form with

```
<!-- Results -->
        <h4 id="results-text"> <b id="search-string"></b></h4>
```

where search-string is replaced with the query.

I have put this into **jquery**

```
var hidden = "search-string";
$('input[name=myField]').val(hidden);
```

but nothing really happens, i get an empty output.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `$_GET['search-query']` parameter, just output it to input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myField" id="myField" value="<?php echo $_GET['search-query']; ?>" />
```

Comment: I have a seperate file search.php, so I have to pass this from search.php to index.php with sessions?

Comment: @user3794172 Well, if you send request from form to search.php via _GET and do not redirect this request, than you can use _GET directly. If redirecting, than yes, use session to get last search text.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you do not actually get anything from jquery.

Change your script to:

```
var hidden = $("#search-string").text();
$('input[name=myField]').val(hidden);
```

Comment: `hidden` variable is string, so it ok to pass string variable to `.val()`